# how can I rectify this error react-native text input effects package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I encountered this error
Iam using Expo

[image: error image]

github  https://github.com/halilb/react-native-textinput-effects

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please , share yours code here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import Sae, { Fumi } from "react-native-textinput-effects";
   <Fumi
                label={"Course Name"}
                iconClass={FontAwesomeIcon}
                iconName={"university"}
                iconColor={"#f95a25"}
                iconSize={20}
                iconWidth={40}
                inputPadding={16}
              />